# mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, collections

I want to list all the collection, created under my database. I know the query

> db.getCollectionNames();

But it listing only - [ "system.indexes", "system.users" ]

I tried

> show collections

it listed following - system.indexes, system.users

It is not showing me my collections. How can i see all my collections ?

Comment: You're probably in the wrong database.  Run `use dbname` in the shell to switch to the database named `'dbname'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see all the collections in the current database using the `mongo` shell:

- `db.getCollectionNames()` returns the collections in the current database as a JavaScript array
- `show collections` prints the collections in the current database as a list

If you aren't seeing the expected collections, you can check the current database with:

```
db.getName()
```

If you want to see all collections in all databases, here's some JavaScript that should do the trick:

```
db.adminCommand("listDatabases").databases.forEach(function (d) {
    sdb = db.getSiblingDB(d.name);
    print("Collections in database: "+d.name);
    printjson(sdb.getCollectionNames())
    print("")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there must be more than one driver out there.
I did

```
npm install mongodb
```

to install the driver and I think the driver I get is the one documented here

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/

It does not have getCollectionNames() or collectionNames() but it does have collections()